# Как убрать пустое пространство в изображении при использовании `Aspect Fit`

Tags: swift

Я вывожу данные в `tableview`
Мне нужно вывести изображение
В `Content Mode` я ставлю `Aspect Fit`
У меня получается что то типа такого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать пустое белое пространство сверху и снизу изображения?

Comment: Какая высота у ячейки в tableView и сколько всего ячеек в таблице?

Comment: Высота динамическая, количество ячеек тоже, все загружается по апи

Comment: @Marshall Добавьте код и скриншоты разметки экрана.